# How can I "add aliases" to enum values when I don't control the source?

Tags: c++, enums, alias, subclassing

(Followup question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40607013/1593077))

I'm writing a program that uses a library, whose header file defines

```
enum foo : unsigned { first_foo, second_foo };
```

Now, I want to add some aliases to `foo` values. If I were in control of the library's source, I would write:

```
enum foo : unsigned { 
    first_foo,
    second_foo,
    best_foo   = first_foo,
    worst_foo  = second_foo,
    oldest_foo = first_foo,
    newest_foo = second_foo; 
};
```

... but I don't control the source. So, I would have liked to write:

```
enum bar : foo { 
    best_foo   = first_foo,
    worst_foo  = second_foo,
    oldest_foo = first_foo,
    newest_foo = second_foo; 
};
```

but that is invalid C++, since foo is not an integral type. If I try to work around it and use the underlying type:

```
enum bar : std::underlying_type<foo> {  /* etc. etc. */ }
```

it compiles, but then - I don't get values of type foo, and I get compiler warnings about comparison between `bar`'s and `foo`'s.

I can use `static const` variables:

```
    static const auto best_foo    = first_foo;
    static const auto worst_foo   = second_foo,
    static const auto oldest_foo  = first_foo,
    static const auto newest_foo  = second_foo;
```

but I don't want to risk them going into the text section, or the symbol table.

So, what should I do?

Comment: Is making `bar` a strict superset of `foo` a reasonable solution for you?

Comment: @TartanLlama: That's not possible. the library has determined which values a `foo` may have, and my `bar`s are, specifically, `foo`'s which need to interact with code expecting `foo`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can define `enum bar` completely separately, then overload the unary `+` operators for both bar and foo to return foo:

```
constexpr foo operator + ( bar const input )
{
    return static_cast <foo> ( input );
}

constexpr foo operator + ( foo const input )
{
    return input;
}
```