# assignment to enum - lvalue required in c/c++

Tags: c++, c

While tying my hands on `enum` I found that:

1. `enum` can't be assigned any literal (even of integral types).

   ```
   enum sign{alpha,beta};
   alpha=4;       //error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
   ```

Regarding this I can't understand how `enum` is not a lvalue since it has a name (identifier).

2. In **C++ Primer** it has been given that:

> An object of enumeration type may be initialized or assigned only by one of its enumerators or by another object of the same enumeration type.

It has also shown in an example that:

```
enum p1{var1A,var1B};
enum p2{var2A,var2B};

var2A=var1A //Error: var2A is not a p2 enumerator -> as written in the book
var2A=var2B //Correct as per the book
```

But why on assigning the *correct* value all I am getting is the same `lvalue` error which is being shown in point **1**.

Comment: "An object of enumeration type" is not the same as an "enumerator". You are trying to assign a value to an enumerator, not an object of enumeration type. Compare: `sign s; s = alpha;`

Comment: It has a name, but it cannot be assigned a new one, as it has a constant value by construction (here 0). Change your book, throw it is a fire.

Comment: `alfa` is not a lvalue, only lvalue can be assigned

Comment: When using C++ you should generally prefer `enum class` over plain `enum`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl is it a part of version before c++11? (as the project I am working on requires that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because something has a name, doesn't mean it's an *lvalue*. It's more complicated that than. For example, types have names and they're not values at all! You're probably thinking of expressions that use the name of a *variable*, which do tend to be lvalues. But an enumerator is not a variable.

Enumerators are not only constants, but they are also *prvalues*, so not only is the error message correct but it is also worded properly.

You can read about [value categories on cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category).

If your book said that `var2A=var2B` is valid, you would need a new book, because that is nonsense. But the quoted passage does not support your assertion. It's saying that you can create a fresh `sign` and initialise it from any of those enumerations, like `sign mySign = var2A;`.

Comment: It's most definitely not an lvalue. It doesn't designate an object and you cannot take its address => not an lvalue.

Comment: @PSkocik There.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize your enumerators inside the enumerator-list, not outside of it:

```
enum sign { alpha = 4, beta };
```

`alfa` is not a *"an object of enumeration type"*, it's an [enumerator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum). If you had:

```
sign myenum;
```

then `myenum` would be *"an object of enumeration type"* and then you could do:

```
myenum = alpha;
```

or:

```
myenum = beta;
```

If you really want to go down that route, then use scoped enums (whose underlying type you can specify) and some [std::underlying_type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/underlying_type) magic as a workaround:

```
enum class p1 { var1A, var1B };
enum class p2 : std::underlying_type<p1>::type { var2A = p1::var1A, var1B = var1A};
```

as you can't really have an enum as an underlying type of another enum.

More on the subject in this SO post:

[Why can't I have an enum as the underlying type of another enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40607013/why-cant-i-have-an-enum-as-the-underlying-type-of-another-enum)

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
enum sign{alpha,beta};
```

It's almost exactly equivalent to

```
#define alpha 0
#define beta 1
```

`alpha` and `beta` will be equivalent to `0` and `1` respectively, and just like C/C++ don't allow you to assign into `0` or `1`, so will the enumerator constants be unassignable.

(In addition to the integer constants, `enum sign{alpha,beta}` also additionally creates an integer type called `enum sign`, whose values a debugger may print as `alpha` and `beta` instead of just `0` and `1`, plus enumerator constants respect scoping and and `#define`s don't, but otherwise `int` `#define`s and enumerator constants are basically interchangable.)

Comment: It's almost not equivalent to that at all

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit How do you figure? After preprocessing and without using a debugger, I don't think you can distinguish `alpha` and `beta` from `0` and `1` in C.

Comment: They're totally different things. One is a name in a scope with a type; the other, after preprocessing, is an integer literal. And just because something is a constant prvalue doesn't mean it's a literal (though non-string literals are constant prvalues). (This is particularly clear with scoped enums.) Sure, you can write a program for which the difference is not observable after compilation but that's true for loads of things.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Apart from scoping, I don't think you can (at least for plain old C enumerator constants) observe the difference even during compilation post-preprocessing. That in my book makes them almost equivalent (or at least not "almost not equivalent at all").

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a6bb111b64dda208 Constants and macros are fundamentally different things.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Which is why I keep saying after/post preprocessing.

Comment: But the problem I demonstrated _is_ visible post-preprocessing. It's the compiler that rejects the code, because the preprocessed program contains a call to a non-existent function. If your argument is "there are no differences other than the differences" then I do agree!

Comment: Pedanticism about reproducing edge cases aside, we have a hard enough time as it is teaching people the differences between constants and preprocessor macros, and I think it's important not to further blur that line when we don't need to. A enumerator and a preprocessor definition are just fundamentally different things, living in different categories of things, and I don't see a reason to lie about that!